# How to use DMA in Application

Tags: c, stm32, dma, adc

I am using stm32wl55JC1. I am making FFT project with ADC mic. I manage to get this work with my workspace but now I need to implement this on Application here [github](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeWL/tree/main/Projects/NUCLEO-WL55JC/Applications/SubGHz_Phy/SubGHz_Phy_PingPong) . So I try to implement my project, but I fail and fail a lot.

Finally, I manage to get this project work like this:

```
static uint32_t ADC_ReadChannels(uint32_t channel)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_ReadChannels_1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_ReadChannels_1 */
  uint32_t ADCxConvertedValues = 0;
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  MX_ADC_Init();

  /* Start Calibration */
  if (HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Configure Regular Channel */
  sConfig.Channel = channel;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Start Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Wait for end of conversion */
  HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

  /** Wait for end of conversion */
  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc);   /* it calls also ADC_Disable() */

  ADCxConvertedValues = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc);

  HAL_ADC_DeInit(&hadc);

  return ADCxConvertedValues;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_ReadChannels_2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_ReadChannels_2 */
}
```

but I want to use dma, so I try to write something like this:

```
static uint32_t ADC_ReadChannels(uint32_t channel)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_ReadChannels_1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_ReadChannels_1 */
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC_Init();


  /* Start Calibration */
  if (HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Configure Regular Channel */
  sConfig.Channel = channel;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc, (uint32_t*) txBuf, 128);


  return txBuf[35];
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_ReadChannels_2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_ReadChannels_2 */
}
```

This code only works 1 time then stops. I don't know why.

Here is my adc and dma settings:

```
void MX_ADC_Init(void)
{

  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc.Instance = ADC;
  hadc.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.LowPowerAutoPowerOff = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_OVERWRITTEN;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon1 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_39CYCLES_5;
  hadc.Init.SamplingTimeCommon2 = ADC_SAMPLETIME_160CYCLES_5;
  hadc.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc.Init.TriggerFrequencyMode = ADC_TRIGGER_FREQ_HIGH;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_MspInit 0 */
    /* ADC clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_ADC_MspDeInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC_CLK_DISABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}


static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);

}
```

Why is dma not working because polling is working.

(In this application, tehere is a file named dma.c but I didn't import it. I try to import and write this dma settings inside it but it didn't work too.)

Comment: `return txBuf[35];` looks like a red flag particularly if the definition is something like `uint32_t txBuf[35];`

Comment: You should only initialise the peripherals once. After that you should be able to call `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()` as many times as you want. It's not clear if that is what you are actually doing. Also note that the data is not ready until the DMA is complete. You're not waiting for that, you're returning a value immediately.

Comment: @KIIV it gives error than I make txBuf global and txBuf[35] return 0;

Comment: @pmacfarlane but I can't use delay, I am using accelerometer too I don't want to block it

Comment: You'll probably need to use an interrupt to signal when the DMA is complete then. That way your CPU can continue doing other things. But the data in `txBuf` won't be valid until the DMA completes. It sounds like you have some design decisions to make.